# What is going on in Theorem 8.2

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, proof-explanation

I'm already lost by the second line, as I don't understand where the final equality comes from. Specifically, I don't know how to get from the middle expression to the third sum.[image] Here is a picture of the problematic part of the proof.

Comment: Can you give us something more specific than "I'm lost" or "I don't understand"?  Not sure how to answer your question if we don't know what your question is.

Comment: Yes, one second.

Comment: Ok @NickPeterson I updated it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that
$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^{m}(s_n-s_{n-1})x^n&=\sum_{n=0}^{m}s_nx^n-\sum_{n=0}^{m}s_{n-1}x^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{m}s_nx^n-\left[s_{-1}+x\sum_{n=1}^{m}s_{n-1}x^{n-1}\right]\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{m}s_nx^n-x\sum_{n=0}^{m-1}s_nx^n\\
&=s_mx^m+\sum_{n=0}^{m-1}s_nx^n-x\sum_{n=0}^{m-1}s_nx^n\\
&=s_mx^m+(1-x)\sum_{n=0}^{m-1}s_nx^n
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: how do you $\LaTeX$ that fast? That's just unfair.

Comment: @Thomas Lived there for too long, I guess. :-)  Every assignment/paper/research note for 9 years of my life

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know it's a trivial question